# The descending chain condition question

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found the solution for the question below and understood how it proceeds,

but I'm not sure if this is legitimate proof.

I mean its true that we can continue to find $N_{k+1}$ for $N_k$

but I'm not sure that this is mathematically fine and I need to prove that this process 
can be infinitely continued.

We know $N_r = N_{r+1}$ holds but why $N_{r+1} = N_{r+2}$?

Some ideas or help please!

[image]

Comment: I was talking about "DCC implies mC" part!

Comment: Also, we know N_r = N_r+1 holds but why N_r+1 = N_R+2?

Comment: Ok, now I can see your problem. How can we be "sure" that this processes do indeed go on infinitely? I am no expert on this "foundational issues" but I feel the Axiom of choice is required here.

Comment: $N_r=N_{r+1}=N_{r+2}=\dots$ because we have both the fact that $N_r\supseteq N_{r+1}\supseteq N_{r+2}\supseteq\dots$ and that $N_r$ does not properly contain any of the $N_i$.  Well, if $N_{r+2}$ is not contained in $N_{r+1}=N_r$, the only other possibility is that it is a proper subset of $N_r$, which we know can't happen!

Comment: @dado: the axiom of dependent choice is certainly sufficient, and may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more formally, let $S$ be a set of ideals of $R$. 
If $S$ is empty, then mC holds for $S$ vacuously.
Assume therefore that $S\ne \emptyset$, let $N_1\in S$ be an arbitrary element.
Also assume thet mC does not hold. Then there exists a map $f\colon S\to S$ such that $f(a)\subsetneq a$ for all $a\in S$ (the existence of this $f$ requires the Axiom of Choice, though some "milder" form may suffice).
Now we define a function $g\colon \mathbb N\to S$ recursively per $g(1)=N_1$ and $g(n+1)=f(g(n))$. Then $g$ gives us an infinite  strictly descending sequence of ideals and DCC does not hold. Thus conversely, DCC implies mC.